# Varaible string input to resources

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a mvc5 project that has static texts in resource files
In my view I have a string value that i need to look for in the resourse file

My resource file looks like this:

- _1 = Saturday
- _2 = Sunday

If I ask for the resource value like this, everything works just fine:

```
    PropertyAvailabilityTexts._1
```

But the value I want to look for is always different, depanding of previus input and looks like this:

```
          @foreach (var dayInterval in Model.DayIntervals)
            {
                <td>
                    @dayInterval.Item1 - @(dayInterval.Item1 + dayInterval.Item2 - 1)
                </td>
            }
```

So my question is: 
Is it possible to get string value from a resource file using a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `string translated = Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(key);` where `Resources` is your resource file and `key` is your translation key, e.g. "_1".

Comment: Always happy to help :>